# Mailto open an email program but body is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

The text 'Aemail' doesn't show up in the body

[image]

```
window.location.href = 'mailto:wxxn2354@corp.netease.com?&subject=Hello&body=Aemail'
```

Comment: why you have & before subject? it is the first query param so not required.

Comment: I deleted the first &, but the body is still missing.

Comment: After removing the `&` it worked at my computer (Windows 7)

Comment: I just paste your `window.location.... Aemail'` and it works for me. I tried it on Firefox's console.(Mac Sierra)

Comment: That's the beauty of `mailto:` links: it's up to each browser and email client combination to decide if and how they implement the feature and if and how they interact each other. Seriously: there isn't a reliable way to send email without server-side technologies.

Comment: I tried on Foxmail and Outlook, it all worked well! But on Flashmail, which I download form [link](http://fm.163.com/), it still cann't work.(Windows 7)